# Tableview how to edit cells

Tags: java, javafx

I started learn javafx yesterday for my project. I trying fast learn taking data from database to javafx. Today I take from example how to bind query from db to tableview
http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/
This is working nice and now I looking why on my function

```
public void buildData(){
    Connection c ;
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try{
        c = DBConnect.connect();
        String SQL = "SELECT * from tabela";
        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
        for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;                
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>() {                    
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                }                    
            });

            t.getColumns().addAll(col); 
            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }

        /********************************
        * Data added to ObservableList *
        ********************************/
        while(rs.next()){
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
            data.add(row);
        }

        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        t.setItems(data);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");             
    }
}
```

can't edit cells after click. What is what change I need?

Comment: The [Oracle JavaFX TableView tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) has sections focused on editing TableView data.

Comment: I looking on this but i miss this. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t.setEditable(true), where t it's your TableView object. Without further info/code, it's the first shot to try.
The same for every TableColumn object.